# could we create a society with no knowledge of the outside world?

Tags: internal-consistency, society

could there be a way for, lets say our government, to start an isolated society which does not have any knowledge of the outside world? could this be possible?

Comment: Could you please edit your question? I can just understand what you are saying, but more detail would be nice.

Comment: Welcome bigboi. Please take the [tour] and read-up in the [help] about how we work. at the moment your question is too broad because of lack of details. When you say "our government" - you would need to take into account that the site is visited be a broad international demographic - ie. you need to be more specific. Do you mean "Taken at birth and raised by wolves on a remote island?" or another scenario - you would need to specify. What we do here is answer *specific well-defined* world-building questions.

Comment: As in, like *The City of Ember*?

Comment: *Our* government cannot, but maybe *your* government can. What country does *your* government govern? Also, you have the small problem of starting up that society; you obviously cannot use people taken from the general population, because they have knowledge of the outside world...

Comment: What would "our government" gain from a small "society" of disease-ridden hardscrabble subsistence farmers with bad teeth? Seems like a lot of effort for very little reward.

Comment: How sophisticated of a society and at what scale? Would it count to just dump a few dozen people on a deserted island in the middle of a large ocean with no means of traveling off of it? Or do you imagine something much more expansive than that?

Answer (score 3):

Possible? Absolutely. Practical? No. Consider the fact that there are dozens of uncontacted  tribes in the Amazon rainforest, and one on North Sentinel Island. These people have almost no knowledge about the outside world, and it would not be terribly difficult to recreate the conditions, if you have enough resources, patience  and lack all ethical boundaries.

You would simply snatch some people, preferably people from uncontacted tribes, and  put them on an  isolated island. These people would have very little knowledge of the world to start with, and over the generations they’d lose credible memory of what came before.  Make sure none of the founders know how to build boats or navigate.

Why uncontacted tribes? Because they’d start with less information about the broader world, and would be much more likely to survive and reproduce on an isolated island compared to say children or westerners

It’s really not hard to keep people ignorant of the world when you put them on a small island with no means of information or escape.